# DSE solr_query using CQL lost lists in result

Tags: solr, cassandra

I am using DSE 4.7.3, cluster is set up with 3 solr nodes and 3 cassandra nodes.

Created table as following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS somejob.jobs (
    job_id uuid,
    files list<text>,
    PRIMARY KEY (job_id)
);
```

schema.xml is as following:

```
<schema name="jobs" version="1.5">
 <types>
  <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="uuid" class="solr.UUIDField"/>
 </types>
 <fields>
    <field name="job_id" type="uuid" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="files" type="text" indexed="false" multiValued="true" stored="true"/>
 </fields>

<defaultSearchField>job_id</defaultSearchField>
<uniqueKey>job_id</uniqueKey>
</schema>
```

When I try in cqlsh:

```
SELECT files from somejob.jobs where job_id = f7eccbdf-d20f-426a-559b-713b308ad3f5;
```

Records are returned correctly.

However, when I try:

```
SELECT files from somejob.jobs where solr_query='job_id:f7eccbdf-d20f-426a-559b-713b308ad3f5';
```

The files field is an empty array, other fields are fine as expected.

The most tricky part is, when I try to use DSE solr admin console to query the same thing, 'files' is returned correctly.

Can someone help me figure out what's going on there, please?

Comment: can you share your solrconfig.xml? does it contain following <requestHandler class="com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.handler.component.CqlSearchHandler" name="solr_query" />

Comment: Also check the set consistency level and the logs in case any error is encountered when you fire solr_query through CQL

Comment: solrconfig.xml has     <requestHandler name="solr_query" class="com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.handler.component.CqlSearchHandler"/>. since I use solr_query, the consistency level should be ONE. And no errors or warnings in log(I don't know how to change the log level, just use the default level).

Comment: are you saying you have 6 nodes total? and are the c* and solr nodes in different DCs within the cluster?

Comment: @LHWizard, 6 nodes in the same DC.

Comment: [Datastax recommend](http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.7/datastax_enterprise/deploy/deployWkLdSep.html) separate DCs within the cluster for solr and cassandra. I don't know if this contributes to your problem.